# Block matrix multiplication and inverses

Tags: linear-algebra

We fix $n>\ell >0$ and write all $n\times n $ matrices over $\Bbb Q$
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_ 
      {22}\end{pmatrix}$$
where $A_{11}$ is a $\ell\times \ell$ matrix and $A_{12},A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ are in suitable sizes.

a) Which sizes do these matrices $A_{12},A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ have? 
b) Show that for arbitrary matrices
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_ 
      {22}\end{pmatrix}$$ $$B=\begin{pmatrix}B_{11}&B_{12}\\B_{21}&B_ 
      {22}\end{pmatrix}$$
that, $$A\times B=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}B_{11}+A_{12}B_{21}&A_{11}B_{12}+A_{12}B_{22}\\A_{21}B_{11}+A_{22}B_{21}&A_ 
      {21}B_{12}+A_{22}B_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$

For a) Since the matrices are $n\times n$ and $A_{11}$ is $\ell \times \ell$, shouldn't all the other matrices be the same sizes? I mean also $\ell \times \ell$. I am not quite sure i understood this correctly. I assume by "all $n\times n$ matrices" they mean the block matrix A. And since $A_{11}$ is $\ell \times \ell$, all others have to be the same in order for A to be $n\times n$. Or should i multiply the whole thing out and go for the rule of matrix multiplication that the row of the first matrix should be the same as the column of the second matrix? I am not quite sure what the question wants.

As for b): Does this work for all matrices? I was under the impression that there were some restrictions for submatrices of B?

Comment: Remember the number of columns of $A_{11}$ and $A_{12}$ must add to $n$. So if $A_{11}$ has $\ell$ columns, then how many columns must $A_{12}$ have? Similarly for the columns of $A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ and for the rows of the matrices.

Comment: For part b), it seems that the author meant to say that $B$ is $n \times n$ with $B_{11}$ of size $\ell \times \ell$.

Comment: @cappy64ftb $A_{12}$ must also have $\ell$ columns? So $2\times \ell =n$?

Comment: So if we use concrete numbers we can see this can't be true. For example if A is a $6\times 6$ matrix and $\ell = 2$ then obviously $2\times \ell \neq 6$. So in this example we are saying $A_{11}$ has 2 columns and $A$ has 6 columns. How many columns must $A_{12}$ have then?

Comment: @cappy64ftb aha yeah i was thinking something else, so it must be $n-\ell$

Comment: All though I am wondering why does the number of rows of say A11 has to be the same as the number of rows of A12...I searched a bit on the internet, couldn't find anything useful

Comment: And for b) Is there a smart way of doing that? I am doing that one and the notation is giving me a headache..

Comment: I posted an "answer" because putting a matrix in the comments wasn't a good idea. Also this may be of use to you for part b.) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112724/need-help-proving-blockwise-property-of-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the block structure of $A$ can be expressed as:

\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1\ell} & | & a_{1 (\ell+1)} &\cdots &a_{1n}           \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & |& \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots      \\
a_{\ell1} & \cdots & a_{\ell\ell} & | & a_{\ell (\ell+1)} & \cdots & a_{\ell n} \\
-&-&-&-&-&-&- \\
a_{(\ell+1)1} & \cdots & a_{(\ell + 1)\ell} & | & a_{(\ell+1)(\ell+1)} &\cdots &a_{(\ell+1)n}           \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & |& \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots      \\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{n\ell} & | & a_{n(\ell+1)} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}

So we can here that the number of rows of $A_{11}$ and $A_{12}$ must match or else we would have a different block structure. Likewise for the number of rows of $A_{21}$ and $A_{22}$ and for the corresponding columns.

It is also easy to see that $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ are $\ell\times (n-\ell)$ and $(n-\ell)\times \ell$ matrices, respectively, as the number of rows and columns of the block matrices must add up to $n$. Thus if $m$ is the number of columns of $A_{12}$ we must have $\ell + m = n$ yielding $m=n-\ell$.

To prove part b.) it is simply just using the definition of matrix multiplication and going case by case for each block matrix. Tedious? Of course. But doable nevertheless.